# Practical application of lightweight block cipher

Tags: block-cipher, lightweight

Are any lightweight block cipher ciphers adopted in real-time? If yes, what cipher and which application?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "in real-time"? They are constant-time anyway which is the compsci definition of real-time. :)

Comment: @Elias Maybe he's an early pioneer living in the cloud using fast time ;) ShanRe, we're not really about lists and such. *Why* do you need to know this.

Comment: Am trying to understand the practical usage of light-weight ciphers. For instance AES is used in LoRaWAN protocol for authentication. Similarly are there any lightweight ciphers like PRESENT and CLEFIA recommended or used in specific protocols/applications?